# What are the things with information that are under or next to museum exhibits called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

[image: museum example]

I'm trying to figure out what the things the arrows are pointing to are called. (For a school assignment.)

Answer (score 1):

They're called [*museum labels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_label).

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for **plaque** - see [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plaque).